# How can I solve Pyswip error with exit code 3?

Tags: python, prolog

I tried to run a python program that uses pyswip prolog library.

When I try to run this program using PyCharm It shows this message:

`Assertion failed: 0, file /home/swipl/src/swipl-devel/src/pl-fli.c, line 263`

`Process finished with exit code 3`

What is the cause? Is it an error of libraries incompatibility or somethign?

I tried installing a different version of Python (eg. 3.10 -> 3.9) but It still remains